# what should we use SOAP and when should use REST?

Tags: java, rest, soap

When should we use SOAP and when should we use REST? 
Can someone give a justifiable answer to this.

This was asked during an interview. I said it's up to contract with other parties. I don't know whether this is right or wrong. Can someone help with this.

SOAP I mean structure like below.

```
    <?xml version='1.0' Encoding='UTF-8' ?>
    <env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"> 
     <env:Header>
      <m:reservation xmlns:m="http://travelcompany.example.org/reservation" 
            env:role="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope/role/next">
       <m:reference>uuid:093a2da1-q345-739r-ba5d-pqff98fe8j7d</m:reference>
       <m:dateAndTime>2007-11-29T13:20:00.000-05:00</m:dateAndTime>
      </m:reservation>
      <n:passenger xmlns:n="http://mycompany.example.com/employees" 
            env:role="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope/role/next">
       <n:name>Fred Bloggs</n:name>
      </n:passenger>
     </env:Header>
     <env:Body>
      <p:itinerary xmlns:p="http://travelcompany.example.org/reservation/travel">
       <p:departure>
         <p:departing>New York</p:departing>
         <p:arriving>Los Angeles</p:arriving>
         <p:departureDate>2007-12-14</p:departureDate>
         <p:departureTime>late afternoon</p:departureTime>
         <p:seatPreference>aisle</p:seatPreference>
       </p:departure>
       <p:return>
         <p:departing>Los Angeles</p:departing>
         <p:arriving>New York</p:arriving>
         <p:departureDate>2007-12-20</p:departureDate>
         <p:departureTime>mid-morning</p:departureTime>
         <p:seatPreference></p:seatPreference>
       </p:return>
      </p:itinerary>
     </env:Body>
    </env:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1):

In very few words, using REST you can describe the same operations you may expect from a database find, insert, update, delete. In REST such operation are paired with the HTTP command: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE. That's also why REST is referred as "state transfer" in the sense that you move objects in/out like in a database, in other words changing the state of your "model".

On the other hand SOAP reflect more a Remote Call Procedure (RPC) where, the message is heavily structured by XML, this means that in SOAP you do not simple transfer data but submit commands. In SOAP you can define, like in a programming language, methods and parameters. Regarding this last point to allow a client to use the "methods" (really are well structured XML messages, with name and parameters) defined by a SOAP service, the same service has to publish an XML document describing what messages and their format it can accept: if the method does not exists, it throws an error like "Service not supported".

Comment: agreed somewhat

Comment: is there anything else could be reason?